# Adding an event listener to DOM elements pushed into an array

Tags: javascript, html

Apologies for the poorly-worded question. It's my first question here!

I am trying to make an application whereby one can log the scores of players from any game and see the results at the end of the game (see the code snippet below).

So far, I have managed to push players and their scores (initially empty arrays) into the main array and thereby presented these players in a list (see below):

**HTML**

```
    <h1>Score Keeper</h1>

    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Player's Name" id="enterPlayer">
    <input type="submit" id="enterPlayerBtn" value="Enter Player">

    <div>
        <ul id="scoreConsole"></ul>
    </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var players = [];

var enterPlayer = document.querySelector("#enterPlayer"); 
var enterPlayerBtn = document.querySelector("#enterPlayerBtn");
var scoreConsole = document.querySelector("#scoreConsole"); 

//PUSHES OBJECTS INTO ARRAYS OF PLAYERS
addPlayer = () => {
    var entered = enterPlayer.value;
    players.push(
        {
            player: entered, 
            score: [] 
        }
    ); 
    enterPlayer.value = ""; 
}

//DISPLAYS PLAYERS ENTERED INTO ARRAY: 
var i=0;
createdPlayers = () => {
    var toAdd = document.createDocumentFragment();
        var newLi = document.createElement("li"); 
        newLi.className="each-player"; 
        newLi.innerHTML = players[i].player + " " + "<input type='number' placeholder='enter score' class='enterScore'>" + "<input type='submit' class='submitScoreBtn'>";   
        toAdd.appendChild(newLi);
    i++; 
    scoreConsole.appendChild(toAdd); 
}

enterPlayerBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
 addPlayer(); 
 createdPlayers(); 
});
```

This gives me a list with the players' names, inputs to enter scores and buttons to log the scores. So far, so good.

But...

I am just trying to get each button to work. As you can see above, I gave each submit button classes ("submitScoreBtn"). I'm at the stage where I want to make sure that my new buttons work. Here's my code so far:

```
var enterScore = document.querySelectorAll(".enterScore"); 
var submitScore = document.querySelectorAll(".submitScoreBtn");

for (var x = 0; x < submitScore.length; x++){
    submitScore[x].addEventListener("click", () => {
        alert("selected"); 
    });
}
```

I initially was getting errors without adding a for loop. Now I don't get any errors, but I also don't get any alerts. I'm just not sure why these buttons do not work.

Please see the code snippet below.

```js
var players = [];

var enterPlayer = document.querySelector("#enterPlayer"); 
var enterPlayerBtn = document.querySelector("#enterPlayerBtn");
var scoreConsole = document.querySelector("#scoreConsole"); 

//PUSHES OBJECTS INTO ARRAYS OF PLAYERS
addPlayer = () => {
    var entered = enterPlayer.value;
    players.push(
        {
            player: entered, 
            score: [] 
        }
    ); 
    enterPlayer.value = ""; 
}

//DISPLAYS PLAYERS ENTERED INTO ARRAY: 
var i=0;
createdPlayers = () => {
    var toAdd = document.createDocumentFragment();
        var newLi = document.createElement("li"); 
        newLi.className="each-player"; 
        newLi.innerHTML = players[i].player + " " + "<input type='number' placeholder='enter score' class='enterScore'>" + "<input type='submit' class='submitScoreBtn'>";   
        toAdd.appendChild(newLi);
    i++; 
    scoreConsole.appendChild(toAdd); 
}

enterPlayerBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
 addPlayer(); 
 createdPlayers(); 
});

var enterScore = document.querySelectorAll(".enterScore"); 
var submitScore = document.querySelectorAll(".submitScoreBtn");

for (var x = 0; x < submitScore.length; x++){
    submitScore[x].addEventListener("click", () => {
        alert("selected"); 
    });
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Score</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Score Keeper</h1>

        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Player's Name" id="enterPlayer">
        <input type="submit" id="enterPlayerBtn" value="Enter Player">

        <div>
            <ul id="scoreConsole"></ul>
        </div>

        <script src="game.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` are not dynamic: it selects what's in the DOM when it's executed, if the elements are added afterwards, they will not be in the selection (so basically only what's initially in th html will be selected)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements). Specifically, [this answer does not require jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27373951/215552).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being as you're dynamically creating the buttons, it might be easier to simply add the function to the button's `onclick`.

You can still access the `event` object from this click by sending it as a parameter, like:

```js
<input type='submit' onclick='submitScoreClick(event)' class='submitScoreBtn'>
```

```js
var players = [];

var enterPlayer = document.querySelector("#enterPlayer"); 
var enterPlayerBtn = document.querySelector("#enterPlayerBtn");
var scoreConsole = document.querySelector("#scoreConsole"); 

//PUSHES OBJECTS INTO ARRAYS OF PLAYERS
addPlayer = () => {
    var entered = enterPlayer.value;
    players.push(
        {
            player: entered, 
            score: [] 
        }
    ); 
    enterPlayer.value = ""; 
}

//DISPLAYS PLAYERS ENTERED INTO ARRAY: 
var i=0;
createdPlayers = () => {
    var toAdd = document.createDocumentFragment();
        var newLi = document.createElement("li"); 
        newLi.className="each-player"; 
        newLi.innerHTML = players[i].player + " " + "<input type='number' placeholder='enter score' class='enterScore'>" + "<input type='submit' onclick='submitScoreClick(event)' class='submitScoreBtn'>";   
        toAdd.appendChild(newLi);
    i++; 
    scoreConsole.appendChild(toAdd); 
}

enterPlayerBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
 addPlayer(); 
 createdPlayers(); 
});

var enterScore = document.querySelectorAll(".enterScore"); 
var submitScore = document.querySelectorAll(".submitScoreBtn");

function submitScoreClick (e) {
  alert("selected");
};
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Score</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Score Keeper</h1>

        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Player's Name" id="enterPlayer">
        <input type="submit" id="enterPlayerBtn" value="Enter Player">

        <div>
            <ul id="scoreConsole"></ul>
        </div>

        <script src="game.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

At the point in time when this code is run:

```js
for (var x = 0; x < players.length; x++){
    submitScore[x].addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        event.alert("selected"); 
    });
}
```

`players.length` is equal to `0`. So the code is essentially never executed.

Answer (score 1):

remove the `for` loop and add this code

`document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if ( event.target.classList.contains( 'submitScoreBtn' ) ) {
        alert("selected"); 
    }
}, false);`

```js
var players = [];

var enterPlayer = document.querySelector("#enterPlayer");
var enterPlayerBtn = document.querySelector("#enterPlayerBtn");
var scoreConsole = document.querySelector("#scoreConsole");

//PUSHES OBJECTS INTO ARRAYS OF PLAYERS
addPlayer = () => {
  var entered = enterPlayer.value;
  players.push({
    player: entered,
    score: []
  });
  enterPlayer.value = "";
}

//DISPLAYS PLAYERS ENTERED INTO ARRAY: 
var i = 0;
createdPlayers = () => {
  var toAdd = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var newLi = document.createElement("li");
  newLi.className = "each-player";
  newLi.innerHTML = players[i].player + " " + "<input type='number' placeholder='enter score' class='enterScore'>" + "<input type='submit' class='submitScoreBtn'>";
  toAdd.appendChild(newLi);
  i++;
  scoreConsole.appendChild(toAdd);
}
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('submitScoreBtn')) {
    alert("selected");
  }
}, false);
enterPlayerBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  addPlayer();
  createdPlayers();
});

var enterScore = document.querySelectorAll(".enterScore");
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Score</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Score Keeper</h1>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Player's Name" id="enterPlayer">
  <input type="submit" id="enterPlayerBtn" value="Enter Player">

  <div>
    <ul id="scoreConsole"></ul>
  </div>

  <script src="game.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this is a hint towards the solution, but your code adds the same handler multiple times if you add more than one player

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use variables and `createElement` just like you do with `toAdd`. This way each created entry will remember its own inputs (local variables to the function), and you can use for example the score input variable in the click handler without confusion of which number input belongs to which entry.

I removed the class for the inputs because it's not needed to select them anymore, but you can still add some for styling for example. If you want to add classes to select them all, be sure to run `querySelectorAll` each time, so that added elements are actually selected.

```js
var players = [];

var enterPlayer = document.querySelector("#enterPlayer"); 
var enterPlayerBtn = document.querySelector("#enterPlayerBtn");
var scoreConsole = document.querySelector("#scoreConsole"); 

//PUSHES OBJECTS INTO ARRAYS OF PLAYERS
var addPlayer = () => {
    var entered = enterPlayer.value;
    players.push(
        {
            player: entered, 
            score: [] 
        }
    ); 
    enterPlayer.value = ""; 
}

//DISPLAYS PLAYERS ENTERED INTO ARRAY: 
var i=0;
var createdPlayers = () => {
    var toAdd = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var newLi = document.createElement("li"); 
    newLi.className="each-player"; 
    newLi.innerHTML = players[i].player + " ";
    var enterScore = document.createElement("input");
    enterScore.type = 'number';
    enterScore.placeholder = 'enter score';
    var submitScore = document.createElement("input");
    submitScore.type = 'submit';
    submitScore.addEventListener("click", () => {
        alert("selected score: " + enterScore.value); 
    });
    newLi.appendChild(enterScore);
    newLi.appendChild(submitScore);
    toAdd.appendChild(newLi);
    i++; 
    scoreConsole.appendChild(toAdd); 
}

enterPlayerBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    addPlayer(); 
    createdPlayers(); 
});
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Score</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Score Keeper</h1>

        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Player's Name" id="enterPlayer">
        <input type="submit" id="enterPlayerBtn" value="Enter Player">

        <div>
            <ul id="scoreConsole"></ul>
        </div>

        <script src="game.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: provides the only answer so far that can easily get the value of the number input  associated to the button -> people upvote all the other answers :D